# TLF 2.0 in Flash CS5

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, tlf

I am trying to figure out how I can implement the new Text Layout Framework 2.0 in Flash CS5. There are some Flex and FlashBuilder4 examples, but nothing relating to Flash CS5. How do I update my Flash CS5 to support TLF2.

I am particularly interested in creating new List/Bullets features so some example code for Flash would be great.

Here is the source:
http://sourceforge.net/adobe/tlf/home/

Thank you very much in advance, and happy holidays.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the new .swc with the current one (save the current one just incase the new .swc messes up your install).  the ***textLayout.swc*** for Adobe Flash CS5 is located here:

> / Adobe Flash
>   CS5 / Common / Configuration / ActionScript
>   3.0 / libs / 11.0 / textLayout.swc

you must restart Flash CS5 for the changes to take effect.

---

### Update

it doesn't work.  well, it doesn't work the the Text Tool in the IDE but you certainly can target the new .swc from any of your .as classes.  however, this approach is less UI-friendly as you'll have to code everything yourself without help from the Text Tool.  we'll have to wait for Adobe to update Flash CS5 to include the new TLF 2.0 support in the IDE.